# how can I see the result of 'ping -c 5 127.0.0.1' live using org babel session

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, shell, session

https://github.com/whacked/ob-shstream/blob/master/ob-shstream.el

There's an add-on for org babel that let's you see streaming output of bash shell blocks. It's documentation reads like this:

```
;; the default ob-sh evaluation for shell scripts in org-mode is
;; blocking, so commands like e.g.
;; 
;; #+BEGIN_SRC sh
;; ping -c 5 127.0.0.1
;; #+END_SRC
;;
;; will block when run, and results only become visible when the
;; process terminates. :session may be able to hand this,
;; doesn't currently work for me OOTB. ob-shstream is a simple
;; workaround.
```

The author indicates that :session may be able to handle it. How?
I'm running in to much weirdness after installing https://github.com/whacked/ob-shstream/blob/master/ob-shstream.el,
so I prefer if there a ":session" way of doing it, since ":session" is part of core.